# How to fix 'CREATE SCHEMA' failed error when running EF Code First migrations with Azure Managed Identity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to run EF6 Code First migrations against an Azure SQL database connecting via Azure Managed Identity. There are several migrations to run. The last migration fails. This migration is different to the others because it creates tables in a new schema.

This is the error which is returned when running the Entity Framework Code First migration which creates the new schema:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The specified schema name "uuid@uuid" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.
```

I have logged the SQL commands on the database and the command which appears to be failing is

```
IF schema_id('MyNewSchema') IS NULL
EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA [MyNewSchema]')
```

With the error:

```
<batch_information><failure_reason>Err 2759, Level 16, Server mysqldbname
CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.</failure_reason></batch_information>
```

Here are some details on the system:

- All other migrations before this one succeeded. However, none of those needed to create a new schema
- Using .NET Framework 4.7.1. EF6.2.0.
- Using Azure SQL database.
- Connecting to Azure SQL from an ASP.NET MVC web application using Azure Managed Identity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi).

**Things I've tried**

*1. Adding roles*

The main thing I've tried is using the Microsoft permissions docs to work out what permissions are needed. So far I have added the following roles to the contained user which the App Service running migrations connects as:

```
db_ddladmin
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_securityadmin
db_owner
db_accessadmin
```

(Note that the other migrations worked fine with just db_ddladmin, db_datareader and db_datawriter)

*2. Running migrations as server admin*

I have tried running the migrations as the SQL Server admin user. This works, but we are not allowed to connect as the SQL Server admin user for the production system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run into the same issue using asp.net core 2.2 and EF core. I was trying to use a managed identity to create the schema and got the same error. I found this article which indicates it is a bug - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Database-Support-Blog/Lesson-Learned-54-The-specified-schema-name-name-domain-com/ba-p/369152.

My only workaround has been to create the schema with server admin which isn't ideal.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to update this. I was using EF6.2 (rather than Core). I found that I could create the schema if added the service principal of the web app directly to SQL Server users so I didn't have to use server admin. The error I had was when I the wep app service principal was part of a group that was added to the Azure SQL users (which is the way the Microsoft docs recommend). But accepting answer as it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `AUTHORIZATION` to the `CREATE SCHEMA` command, it works.

So the statement Entity Framework creates need's to look like this instead:

```
IF schema_id('MyNewSchema') IS NULL
EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA [MyNewSchema] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
```

You can do this by overwriting `ApplicationSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator`

```
    protected override void Generate(EnsureSchemaOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        if (operation is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(operation));
        if (builder is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        if (string.Equals(operation.Name, "dbo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }
        var stringTypeMapping = Dependencies.TypeMappingSource.GetMapping(typeof(string));
        builder
            .Append("IF SCHEMA_ID(")
            .Append(stringTypeMapping.GenerateSqlLiteral(operation.Name))
            .Append(") IS NULL EXEC(")
            .Append(
                stringTypeMapping.GenerateSqlLiteral(
                    "CREATE SCHEMA "
                    + Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name)
                    + " AUTHORIZATION "
                    + Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier("dbo")
                    + Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator))
            .Append(")")
            .AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator)
            .EndCommand();
    }
```

And then registering it:

```
        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer("Your connection string");
            options.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, ApplicationSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
        });
```

(The code above is for EF Core, as I had the issue there)